# python refer to class variable while passing arguments to init

Tags: python, arguments, default, init, class-variables

What I want to achieve:
1. Have a class variable keeping count of number of objects created
2. That variable should not be available to objects/others i.e. private to the class
3. If specific ID is not provided during init, use this counter variable to assign object.ID
I have following python code

```
class UserClass(object) :
    __user_id_counter = 0
    def __init__(self, UserID=__user_id_counter) :
        self.UserID = UserID
        __user_id_counter += 1

myuser = UserClass()
```

but I am getting
`UnboundLocalError: local variable '_UserClass__user_id_counter' referenced before assignment`
I am new to python so kindly help me here :)

Comment: Don't edit the question to indicate the answer. Mark the answer you want to as the answer by clicking the tick.

Comment: @chris-morgan : thanks, I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access `__user_id_counter` an object or class reference is needed. In the argument list `self` or `UserClass` can not be accessed, hence:

```
class UserClass(object) :
    __user_id_counter = 0
    def __init__(self, UserID=None) :
        self.UserID = self.__user_id_counter if UserID is None else UserID
        UserClass.__user_id_counter += 1
```

Comment: thanks, this solves argument passing, but it doesnt increament the counter when next object is created. Using your code I created 3 objects but all of them have 0 as UserID

Comment: You have to increment the class variable. You do this with `self.__class__.__user_id_counter`, like in my answer.

Comment: so instead of `self.__user_id_counter += 1` I should do `self.__class__.__user_id_counter += 1` ??

Comment: Answer is yes. Thanks a lot to both Maxim-Yegorushkin and @Constantinius .

Comment: Downvoted as this answer does *not* solve the problem due to changing it in `self` rather than `UserClass`.

Comment: Fixed. ` UserClass.__user_id_counter += 1`

Comment: @chris-morgan are you saying that I should refer to the class name? Of course this class will be inherited by other classes, so this won't work in that case? what do you suggest?

Comment: @Chris: you are too kind, thanx )

Comment: @Sudhi: if you're using a leading double underscore, you may well run into problems when dealing with it in subclasses anyway, depending a bit on how you do it, due to the name munging that takes place.

Comment: @Sudhi: if you want to use a different counter for each subtype, you're going to need to be very careful in various places about how you do it and where you work with it. The probability is very high that in your first attempt you *will* get it wrong. If you really do want it that way, I'll write an answer explaining what the problems will be and how to avoid them (it ends up quite a bit of work doing it properly).

Comment: @chris-morgan please do so, it will be of immense help ! Are you suggesting that I should make `user_id_counter` a public variable? I always thought that internal variables should be private only.

Comment: @Sudhi: it's the *double* leading underscore which makes it special. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: @chris-morgan : i know, the name mangling means nothing is private in python, but I would rather make it harder for subclasses to access this counter than make it public and allow messing it up.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `self.__user_id_counter`. This also looks up class variables, if the instance variable is not found.

**EDIT:** Sudhi pointed out, that in the argument list, the `self` declaration is not valid. To circumvent this problem try the following:

```
class UserClass(object) :
    __user_id_counter = 0
    def __init__(self, UserID=None) :
        if UserID is None:
            self.UserID = self.__user_id_counter
            self.__class__.__user_id_counter += 1
        else:
            self.UserID = UserID

myuser = UserClass()
```

Comment: if i do `__init__(self, UserID=self.__user_id_counter) :` it says `NameError name self not definied`

Comment: I see. It seems like this is not possible in the argument list. I guess you have to do a little trick. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, I'm renaming `UserClass` to `User` (we know it's a class) and `UserID` to `id` (it's in the `User` class so no need to repeat the "User" bit, and Python style recommends lowercase), and `__user_id_counter` to `__id_counter` (ditto). Read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for Python style guidelines.

So then, our starting point is this:

```
class User(object):
    __id_counter = 0
    def __init__(self, id=None) :
        self.id = self.__id_counter if id is None else id
        __id_counter += 1
myuser = User()
myuser2 = User()
myuser3 = User()
```

Now, the double leading underscore (without a double trailing underscore as in things like `__init__` and `__metaclass__`) is special, and is used for an implementation of class-private variables - read about [private variables in the Python manual](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) for more info. It triggers what's called "name mangling". What it ends up as is with `__id_counter` being renamed to `_User__id_counter` throughout the class. This is both useful and dangerous. In this case, I think it's probably just not necessary.

This can lead to a problem with subclasses.

```
class SpecialUser(User):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__id_counter
```

Now, `SpecialUser()` will trigger an `AttributeError: 'SpecialUser' object has no attribute '_SpecialUser__id_counter'`.

So then the question is, do you want subclasses to have *the same* ID counter, or *their own* ID counters?

- If you want them to have *the same* ID counter, use `User.__id_counter`. *Don't* use `self.__class__.__id_counter` or `type(self).__id_counter` with the `+= 1`, as this will, for a `SpecialUser` instance, set `SpecialUser._User__id_counter` to `User._User__id_counter + 1`, and then `SpecialUser` will use *its own* `_User__id_counter` from this point onwards, which is far from what you want.
- If you want them to have *their own* ID counters, start by using `_id_counter` rather than `__id_counter`, as the name mangling will take you in a direction you don't want to go.

  There are a couple of approaches you can take:

  - Use a metaclass to give each class its own counter variable (a more advanced topic than I can be bothered writing about at the moment, ask for more details if you want to).
  - Put in a line `_id_counter = 0` in each class definition. (If you don't, you'll run into trouble with ID starting point - make a lot of them, e.g. `User(), User(), SpecialUser(), User(), SpecialUser(), SpecialUser(), User()`, and they'll have IDs of (respectively) `0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3` rather than `0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2`.

  An additional inefficiency which would arise from using the name mangling approach here would be that subclasses will have multiple counters in them - `_User__id_counter`, `_SpecialUser__id_counter`, etc.

Comment: this is great, now I understand whats going on inside python when I declare `__id_counter` , I think I will stick with the former case of _same_ ID counter and replace my `__id_counter` with `_id_counter`. Thanks a lot Chris, I am sure I will bug you a lot with more such python queries :D Too bad I cant tick multiple answers for my question :(

Comment: @Sudhi: you can upvote it if you want (click on the up arrow).

Comment: can't, not enough reputation :( I will when I get more reputation on stackoverflow